# getting wss working with stunnel & ratchet

Tags: ssl, websocket, ratchet, stunnel, reactphp

Running Apache v2.4, PHP v5.6 w/ php-fpm, on CentOS 7

So I'm trying to get wss working with stunnel & Ratchet. I've got Ratchet's Hello World (http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world) working successfully with the test code on non-ssl at port 8080. I can telnet from the same machine, as well as telnet from a a different machine.

Through reading, I know that ratchet doesn't support ssl connections, but does by wrapping the communications with stunnel, so I setup stunnel with an appropriate cert listening on port 8443, which appears to be working (as evidenced by the log file).

When I try to make a connection using wss from Firefox's scratchpad, I get the following error: `Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at wss://testserver.testdomain.com:8443` I can see the connection being created through the various log files, however somewhere along the line communications is failing since I can't create a solid wss connection. Any ideas on what I'm missing or where I'm screwing up? Log/code below

**Scratchpad Code**

```
var conn = new WebSocket('wss://testserver.testdomain.com:8443');
conn.onopen = function(e) {
    console.log("Connection established!");
};

conn.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log(e.data);
};
```

**Stunnel config:**

```
cert = /etc/httpd/ssl/ov_wildcard.pem

[hublistener]
accept = 8443
connect = 8080
```

**Stunnel log:**

```
2016.05.11 14:43:28 LOG5[38759:140614807435328]: stunnel 4.56 on x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu platform
2016.05.11 14:43:28 LOG5[38759:140614807435328]: Compiled/running with OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
2016.05.11 14:43:28 LOG5[38759:140614807435328]: Threading:PTHREAD Sockets:POLL,IPv6 SSL:ENGINE,OCSP,FIPS Auth:LIBWRAP
2016.05.11 14:43:28 LOG5[38759:140614807435328]: Reading configuration from file /etc/stunnel/stunnel.conf
2016.05.11 14:43:28 LOG5[38759:140614807435328]: FIPS mode is enabled
2016.05.11 14:43:28 LOG4[38759:140614807435328]: Insecure file permissions on /etc/httpd/ssl/cert.pem
2016.05.11 14:43:28 LOG5[38759:140614807435328]: Configuration successful
2016.05.11 14:45:59 LOG5[38765:140614807430912]: Service [hublistener] accepted connection from ***.***.***.***:39124
2016.05.11 14:45:59 LOG5[38765:140614807430912]: connect_blocking: connected 127.0.0.1:8080
2016.05.11 14:45:59 LOG5[38765:140614807430912]: Service [hublistener] connected remote server from 127.0.0.1:59795
```

**Ratchet sample output:**

```
[zxurian@ariel dev-hub]$ php module/HubListener/websocket.php
New Connection! (307)
New Connection! (317)
Connection 317 sending message "second window line 1
" to 1 other connection
Connection 317 sending message "second window line 2
" to 1 other connection
New Connection! (318)
Connection 318 sending message "GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: testserver.testdomain.com:8443
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0 FirePHP/0.7.4
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Origin: https://testserver.testdomain.com
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate
Sec-WebSocket-Key: PrWlBjR2q6a0syT4oplnAQ==
Cookie: PHPSESSID=ci7102qouvqprhdpk483hv6ar3; exclusive_offers_popup=1; __utma=213556497.27501638.1462814210.1462827970.1462831402.3; __utmc=213556497; __utmz=213556497.1462814210.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utmv=213556497.|1=l=%2F=1
x-insight: activate
Connection: keep-alive, Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade: websocket

" to 2 other connections
```

**Telnet Connection 1**

```
[zxurian@ariel ~]$ telnet 127.0.0.1 8080
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
second window line 1
second window line 2
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: testserver.testdomain.com:8443
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0 FirePHP/0.7.4
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Origin: https://testserver.testdomain.com
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate
Sec-WebSocket-Key: PrWlBjR2q6a0syT4oplnAQ==
Cookie: PHPSESSID=ci7102qouvqprhdpk483hv6ar3; exclusive_offers_popup=1; __utma=213556497.27501638.1462814210.1462827970.1462831402.3; __utmc=213556497; __utmz=213556497.1462814210.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utmv=213556497.|1=l=%2F=1
x-insight: activate
Connection: keep-alive, Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade: websocket
```

Comment: are you using nginx or apache?

Comment: apache v2.4, inital question udpated to reflect.

Comment: Could you to make sure everything is set right also copy your stunnel config?

Comment: stunnel config added

Comment: you should try adding the proxypass that I added to my apache2.conf

Answer (score 0):

I have a Ratchet WebSocket running on my own machine and am also using Apache2.4
To make it work over SSL I did:

Proxy pass the socket

inside (/etc/apache2/)**apache2.conf** I added

```
    //added for the websocket over SSL
    ProxyPass /wss/ ws://alpha.example.com:8080/
```

this passes my websocket running on port 8080 to wss://alpha.example.com/wss/

to make sure your stunnel config is correct, this is what I did
inside of (/etc/stunnel/)**stunnel.conf**

```
cert = /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/cert.pem
key = /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem
[wss]
accept = 8082
connect = 8080
```

REMINDER: change the paths to the keys I used to thee paths your keys are using.

inside the PHP file that starts my server I user port 8080 as in the ratchet example

```
$webSock->listen(8080, '0.0.0.0'); // Binding to 0.0.0.0 means remotes can connect
```

Comment: I'll try the proxy pass tonight to see if that will have it return communications